# android - Immersive mode in Phoenix OS

Tags: android

I have this application running on a tablet with Immersive mode and Kiosk Mode. Everything works fine.

But now I want to run this same at a device with Phoenix OS on it.

I know, its a different platform but there`s a way to run in Phoenix something like Kiosk mode or full screen mode?

Its a Totem Application.

Comment: Phoenix claims to be Android based. If your full screen app doesn't work there they've borked something up.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman the bottom bar still there

Comment: Are you using immersive sticky flags?